# Tensorflow Backend - Bug in "model._make_predict_function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

there's is a bug while running the Tensorflow code, the error code appears like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 76, in <module>
    model = deepmoji_emojis(maxlen, PRETRAINED_PATH)
  File "/home/lifeofpy/LifeofPy/AI Photographer Project/Text-to-Color/deepmoji/model_def.py", line 35, in deepmoji_emojis
    model._make_predict_function()
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute '_make_predict_function
```

and the file **app.py** is like this:

```
# print('Loading model from {}.'.format(PRETRAINED_PATH))
model = deepmoji_emojis(maxlen, PRETRAINED_PATH)
model.summary()
model._make_predict_function()
```

I think the error message is occured by the function 'model._make_predict_function',
I would appreciate any comments on this issue. Thanks!

Comment: what is `deepmoji_emojis` ? Maybe it doesn't give `model` but something different.

Comment: @furas
https://github.com/hon9g/Text-to-Color/blob/master/app.py
it returns a model...

Comment: in what tutorial did you find `_make_predict_function()` ? I tried to find it with Google and it seems it was private function in Keras but probably it was removed from code.

Comment: @furas yeah I tried to find `_make_predict_function()` too, but I wasn't able to find it. Maybe it was an old version of Keras code, and switched to another code. So I'm wondering if there's a new version of `_make_predict_function()`

Comment: As I wrote in answer - `Some old posts suggest to use model.predict() ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find `_make_predict_function()` with Google and it seems it was private function in old `Keras` in [keras.engine.training.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/engine/training.py#L1023) but now `Keras` is part of `tensorflow` and function was removed from code. I can't find `_make_predict_function()` in [tensorflow.keras.engine.training.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py)

---

Some old posts suggest to use `model.predict()` instead of  `model._make_predict_function()` before threads but other posts suggest to duplicate `model` for every thread. But maybe new code in `tensorflow` resolved problem with running it in threads and maybe it doesn't need this function any more.

Answer (score 5):

Use: `model.make_predict_function()`

instead of: `model._make_predict_function()`